# Sum of value in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer, addition

I’m new here. I wanted to sum all the values inside a dictionary, but my values are all strings, I don’t know how to convert the strings to integers…
I really appreciate if anyone can help with it!

Here’s the dictionary with code:

```
dic1 = dict()
dic1 = {'2012-03-06':['1','4','5'],'2012-03-12':['7','3','10']}

for i in dic1:
    print(i,’,’,sum(dic1[i]))
```

I want the output to be like this:

`2012-03-06, 10`
`2012-03-12, 20`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It can be

```
dic1 = dict() 
dic1 = {'2012-03-06':['1','4','5'],'2012-03-12':['7','3','10']} 
for i in dic1: 
    print(i+','+ str(sum(map(int, dic1[i]))))
```

In python3, `map(func,iter)` returns an iterator(list, tuple etc.) of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable

Answer (score 2):

**1st Solution:** you can do this using `map`

```
dic1 = {'2012-03-06':['1','4','5'],'2012-03-12':['7','3','10']}

result_dict = {key: sum(map(int, value)) for key, value in dic1.items()}
print(result_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'2012-03-06': 10, '2012-03-12': 20}
```

**2nd Solution:** And convert into expected output easily

```
dic1 = {'2012-03-06':['1','3','5'],'2012-03-12':['7','3','10']}
for key, value in dic1.items():
    print(f"{key}, {sum(map(int, value))}")
```

Output:

```
2012-03-06, 10
2012-03-12, 20
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I added this code so I can formate them correctly!
for i in result_dict:
 print(f'{i}, {result_dict[i]}')

Comment: @watermelon_soda - You can use second solution as well, if you just want to print the result.